# MySQL query builder? (like Access has in Design View)

Tags: mysql, microsoft-access

Is there any **free** tools that would let me build queries like one can in Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are - you can download the open source [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html) ([screenshots](http://wb.mysql.com/?page_id=35)).

Comment: This looks close, but I am having trouble finding a query designer. I can get the model of the schema to show up, and query things, but I am having trouble finding how to build the query graphically.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no query browser.  MySQL Workbench is indented as a database designer and creates the statements (or database directly) for MySQL.

Comment: I didn't find any query builder on mysql workbench there!!

Answer (score 9):

Try using [SQLyog's](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) powerful Query Builder. It is very easy and intuitive to use.

[image: SQLyog Query Builder Screenshot]

Comment: But it's not free as is asked in question!

Answer (score 1):

i can advice you this tool [Heidi SQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) it very lightweight and also can repeat all important functions of MySQL Workbench

[Here](http://www.heidisql.com/screenshots.php) you can find some screenshoots of this programm

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/) (Not free but has 30 days free trail).

It is a good tool as far as visual query building is concerned. :-)